# "Updating failed" if any text includes "$v()"

Tags: block-editor

If I include any of the following sequence of characters anywhere in any block in Wordpress, I get the red "Updating failed" error when I try to save the draft.

```
$v()

$xyz()

$x   ()
```

Any variety where it looks like $ followed by an identifier followed by the empty parentheses seems to trigger the problem. The following do NOT trigger the problem:

```
$x

$()

$  ()
```

Initially I thought it was because I was using a syntax highlighter plugin; I tried a different plugin and it still failed; and a post with no plugins used still exhibits the problem.

I've tried refresh the page and trying again. I've updated Wordpress to the latest version available (5.2.2).

Comment: When you say block, you're referring to the block editor right? Or are you referring to blocks of code? It isn't clear. Also have you raised this as a bug with the gutenberg github?

Comment: This is the new block editor. And it doesn't matter whether it's a "block of code" or not - any ordinary paragraph with these particular strings in them somewhere trigger the error. p.s. I don't know how to raise a bug with the gutenberg github.

Comment: I've tried poking the values directly into the underlying `posts` table; when this happens, the editor loads the post fine but as soon as it tries to save any changes, or if I try to publish the post, it errors again. I've also tried inserting the html entity for $ instead of a literal `$` and it allows the post to be saved initially, but wordpress keeps converting it back to a simple `$` all the time and then triggers the problem again.